# How to pass parameter values from batch (.bat) file to sql file

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, stored-procedures, cmd

I am trying to run one sql file from windows batch file with userid, password and a third parameter value as input.

From command line I am running this--> **D:\ testmyFolder> mytestbat.bat MYUSER MYPASSWRD INPARAM**

My batch file (D:/testmyFolder/mytestbat.bat) content is as follows:

```
SET USRID=%1 
SET PWD=%2 
SET INPUT1=%3 
SQLPLUS %USRID%/%PWD% @testmy.sql %USRID% %PWD% %INPUT1%>D:/testmyFolder/Log/testmylog.Log;
```

I am not able to run this... Its just opening up the sql file...
Could anyone please help??

Comment: SQLPLUS %1/%2 @testmy.sql %1 %2 %3>D:/testmyFolder/Log/testmylog.Log

Comment: @tony bd your solution is working, so please move it to the answer.

Comment: No can do. I don't play those stupid games. Did you get the lesson, keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

SQLPLUS %1/%2 @testmy.sql %1 %2 %3>D:/testmyFolder/Log/testmylog.Log 
<*As answered by tony bd*>